# webkit-playsinline stops working when returning to page in cordova iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova, html5-video

I have an inline video embedded in the home page of a cordova (phonegap) app for iOS. I have added the necessary allow setting to the config.xml

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
```

and the the video html looks like this

```
<video webkit-playsinline poster="img/videoplaceholder.png" loop class="video" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="media/homepage.iphone.mp4"/>
</video>
```

When the app first launches the video plays inline and works perfectly. But if I navigate away from the homepage and then return, the video opens full screen on page load. 
I have tried moving the video lower in the page to test if it was because the browser was focusing on page load. I have also tried removing autoplay and delay triggering play with JS. I have tested all of the above in iOS7 and iOS8 only as those are my targeted versions.
Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you are returning to the video page. Are you reloading it from scratch or are using javascript to go back like `window.history.go(-1)`

Comment: I have tried both methods. The app is built using angular so I have tried using
    `window.location.hash = 'home'` and `window.history.go(-1)`
both produce the same result

Comment: Here lies the problem, the thing with `hashchange` and `window.history.go(-1)` in iOS webkit, the `<video>` doesn't get parsed properly. You will have to manually trigger the load event by JS `video.load();` or reload the page from scratch using `window.open("/index.html");` to force loading/ parsing the video.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have just tried to use `video.load()` and this still opens the video full screen, and `window.open("/index.html");` seems to produce the same problem too.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add 'allowinlinemediaplayback=YES' to your first window.open call.  So that it looks something like this:

```
window.open('http://google.com', 'Google', 'location=0,status=0,allowinlinemediaplayback=YES');
```

InAppBrowser defaults your allowinlinemediaplayback setting to NO, for some silly reason.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, this fixed it. This answer should be accepted.

Comment: The question isn't about the inappbrowser though.

Comment: You save my day!