# iOS Video playsinline not always playing inline in cordova app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, mobile-safari

Seems like there's a bug in safari web view that causes the video to not play inline under certain circumstances. Rebooting the device solved the issue.

Has anybody seen this before? Is there a way to fix? If not, is there a way to detect a video going full screen and abort it?

Comment: you want to prevent video going to fullscreen or something else? you missed the question part and what type of video it is (means is it `YouTube`, or `Vimeo`)

Comment: @JoeFlateau add this in your config.xml - <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" /> Also add this attribute in your HTML video tag - "webkit-playsinline playsinline"

Comment: @JoeFlateau Any update on this?

Comment: It's html5 video. Not youtube or vimeo. And that preference is already in the config.xml. Like I said, it USUALLY plays inline, but -- seemingly randomly -- plays fullscreen instead until I reboot the device and it's back to inline again.

Comment: @JoeFlateau Feel its more of a device issue then functional. Is it happening in all devices?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, resolved by adding `playsinline` and `webkit-playsinline` to the web app's `<video>` tag:

```
<video src="foo.mp4" playsinline webkit-playsinline />
```

This is a fix introduced by Apple. For iOS 10+ devices, `playsinline` is sufficient. For iOS 8 and iOS 9, both tags are required. Devices below iOS8 do not support HTML5 videos.

From [Safari documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-SW30):

> **webkit-playsinline**: 
>   Indicates that a video element should play inline instead of full-screen. Enabled only in a UIWebView with the allowsInlineMediaPlayback property set to YES.

Comment: I already have both of those attributes on the video. 99% of the time the videos play inline, but that 1% of the time where the video pops up full screen is killing me

Comment: Do you have these attributes in the `<video>` element or are you adding them by JS or some other form?

Comment: Both actually. There's a video that's instantiated through javascript and frames are drawn on a canvas that is in the document, and there are videos that should just play inline and are <video> elements in the document.

Comment: Does this happen on specific videos? Specific devices?

Comment: That's the frustrating part. It happens on the same videos/devices that work most of the time. On my iPhone it plays 99% of the time properly inline, but -- seemingly -- randomly will just pop open full screen.

Comment: And when it does, the full screen mode is consistant? until reboot?

Comment: Usually if I kill the app by swiping it away and relaunch it's fine, only a few times I had to reboot the device completely.

Comment: I'm starting to think it may be an artifact of the cordova hot code push plugin. Seems to happen when that plugin causes the refresh

Answer (score 0):

Have the same issue exactly - video stopped playing inline at times - strangely I discovered this has to do with opening an in-app-browser window (using cordova.InAppBrowser.open) prior to playing videos...

see - 
[webkit-playsinline stops working when returning to page in cordova iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536318/webkit-playsinline-stops-working-when-returning-to-page-in-cordova-ios-app)

Answer (score 0):

this is because your iPhone is in low power mode. If you disable low power mode playsInline works as expected.

I found no solution for this behaviour. Safari forces all video autoplays to stop